# Can Someone please offer guidance

Tags: java

I am so completely confused.  I can not figure out how to make my program actually calculate the percentage I am trying to get it to calculate.  I have gotten my program to ask for input like it should, but it should output the calculation.  Everything I have tried is not working.  Can someone please guide me a little on how to make the calculation work right?  My project is to make a program that calculates the annual compensation of a sales person.  The commission rate is 8% of the annual sales and the sales person has a fixed salary of 30000.  My program is suppose to ask the user to enter annual sales.  It does that.  But then it is suppose to take the entered annual sales amount and figure out the commission earned and display the annual compensation which is the fixed salary + the comission.  I have been working on this one step at a time and checking each step as I go.  For two weeks I have been trying to figure out how to make the calculation work.  All I can get it to do is display 8%.  I know it is missing something, but I am not sure what.  Any help is appreciated in advance.  Thank you.  Here is my code:

```
public class AnnualCompensation {

public static void main(String[] args){

double percentRate = .08;
int fixedSalary = 30000;
double annualSales = 0;
float Percentage;

Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Please enter your annual sales ");

String annual_sales;
annual_sales = user_input.next();


Percentage = (float) ((annualSales*100)/8);

System.out.println("Percentage is: "+.08+"%");
```

Comment: You're not referring to your `Percentage` variable in your last line of code.

Comment: "*All I can get it to do is display 8%*" - what output do you expect of `System.out.println("Percentage is: "+.08+"%");`? Maybe you should print the percentage instead of 0.08?

Comment: Work the calculation by hand, with paper and pencil. If you can do it correctly that way, think carefully about each step and turn it into Java. If you cannot, you need to work on understanding the calculation before trying to program it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 1):

Now `annual_sales` is, obviously a `String` value...

```
String annual_sales = user_input.next();
```

Which isn't going to help you much, as you can't perform calculations on a `String` (that are going to be of any use to you...)

Instead, you need to get a `double` value.  Now you could parse the `String` using `Double.parseDouble(String)`, but to be frank, it's probably just as easy to ask it directly from the scanner...

```
annualSales = user_input.nextDouble();
```

Now, you should also make sure that you calculations are not be boxed to `int`...

```
double Percentage = 0d;
Percentage = ((annualSales*100d)/8d);
```

nb- Seen as you're dealing with a double input, might as well keep all in `double`, less need to make casts every where...

Finally, you need print it...

```
System.out.println("Percentage is: "+ NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(Percentage) +"%");
```

Take a look at...

- [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)
- [Scanner JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getPercentInstance%28%29)

For more details..